# How can I define an Array of Images and create a for loop for it to add into body of multipart data without LIBRARY?

Tags: android, arrays, image, java-8

I have tried to create an array of images looked for examples in treehouse and StackOverflow but many of them telling about creating an array of Int then defining images for the count of this int array.

My problems are first I need to create an array of images second I need to upload them to the server without the library. This array of images should be pass as a parameter to upload function. So that I can upload a single image and multiple images with the same function.

-Post Class

```
public class UploadImage {
    public String multipartRequest(String urlTo, Map<String, String> parmas, File uploadFile, String filefield)  {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String result = "";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        try {
            String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            URL url = new URL(urlTo);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName) + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // Upload POST Data
            if (parmas != null){
                Iterator<String> keys = parmas.keySet().iterator();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    String value = parmas.get(key);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(value);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                }
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            if (200 != connection.getResponseCode()) {
                Log.i("firat", "Failed to upload code:" + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
            }
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            fileInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return  "Error : "  + e.toString();
        }
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

-Usage

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(4);
                params.put("name", "juan");
                params.put("surname", "mata");
                params.put("email", "matta@cimbom.com");
                params.put("password", "1905");


                UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage();
                String result = uploadImage.multipartRequest("http://xxx:xx/xxx/addUser", params, file2, "file");
```

-OnActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                path2 = getPath(this.getApplicationContext(),selectedImageUri);
                file2 = new File(path2);


              //  fileArray[k] = file2;


            } // When an Video is picked
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri ) {
        String result = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( uri, proj, null, null, null );
        if(cursor != null){
            if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
                result = cursor.getString( column_index );
            }
            cursor.close( );
        }
        if(result == null) {
            result = "Not found";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Without using Networking libraries like OkHttp or Retrofit?

Comment: Yes definetly without library

Comment: What have you tried so far and what concrete problems are blocking you from achieving your goal? The question is a bit vague and broad at the moment.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen In my previous question, I shared my codes. I'm sending multipart data using httpurlconnection and it's just a picture and a json. I want to send more than one picture. You can look at my previous question and understand exactly what I mean.

Comment: If you still have the exactly same problem, then there shouldn't be a new question like this.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Edited question. Can you help me?

Comment: [Hm](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically)?

Comment: @m4gic this is not the answer to my question. I've already added a working code and just want to send it as an array.

Comment: You will not be able to do that. What you can do is to use a naming convention and make an array on the server when you process the request I think.

Comment: @m4gic
I've done it before with retrofit as follows.

      MultipartBody.Part[] listOfPhotos  = new MultipartBody.Part[11];
      public int k=0;

      RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
      listOfPhotos[k] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.getName(), mFile);

But I'm currently using HttpUrlConnection